# Phabricator Arcanist unit test for nose2

Tags: python, unit-testing, arcanist, nose2

I have trouble setting up the auto unit test config for my python project.
Normally I just run `nose2` and my tests throughout the project will be discovered and executed. However, I am having a hard time finding relative documents to set up `arc unit`.

I tried adding the followings to `.arcconfig` but nothing happens if I do `arc unit`. It think is assumes all tests are under `tests/` which is not the case for me. My tests are in the same folder as the to-be-tested files.

```
"unit.engine": "NoseTestEngine"
```

Comment: Arcanist docs aren't very clear on this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to write a nose2 test engine which extends ArcanistUnitTestEngine,

here's a good example: https://github.com/tagview/arcanist-extensions/tree/master/tap_test_engine

and refer to the .arcconfig settings